# Forcing HTTPS & Non-WWW on all folders with exceptions in place

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running into an issue where by my subdomains are incorrectly getting `www` appended to them via a htaccess rewrite rule...

My folder structure is as follows:

- `/public_html/index.html` (A maintenance page just in case)
- `/public_html/.htaccess`
- `/public_html/websitename`
- `/public_html/subdomain`
- `/public_html/testsite`
- `/public_html/clone`

My `/public_html/` that's located in my `.htaccess` looks as follows

```
# Force HTTPS & WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} websitename.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websitename/$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.website.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which works perfectly for `websitename.com`, which forces the URL to be rewrote to `https://www.websitename.com`

However it makes my subdomains get incorrectly rewrote to `https://www.subdomain.websitename.com` when it should be `https://subdomain.websitename.com`

**I don't want to have to put the forcing of HTTPS & WWW in the individual website folders...** rather, I'm looking for a solution to make `subdomain` exempt from the rewrite rule.

I tried adding the following condition but it didn't help:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.websitename.com$ [NC]`

Anyone have any idea what I can do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

And add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For multiple domains you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The reason we use the wildcard ones that I provided is because we use a lot of domains and setting all of them up is time consuming and means every new domain needs to be setup... is there no way I can add another condition to stop the rewrite in its steps?